# useEffect does not trigger on context change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component ButtonTile that should change the LayoutContext:

```
export function ButtonTile(button: Omit<IButtonTile, "type">) {
  const layout = useContext(LayoutContext);
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (button.action.type === 'update') {
      // layout changes
    }
  };

  return (
    
    <button className="tile" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
      {button.text}
    </button>
  )
}
```

And another element that should change whenever the context changes:

```
export function Tile({ defaultElement }: {defaultElement?: ElementsType}) {
  const layout = useContext(LayoutContext);
  const [element, setElement] = useState(defaultElement);

  useEffect(() => {
      // setElement(some element)
  }, [layout])

  switch (element?.type) {
    case 'textTile':
      return <TextTile title={element.title} text={element.text} color={element.color} elementKey={element.elementKey} />;
    case 'imageTile':
      return <ImageTile source={element.source} title={element.title} elementKey={element.elementKey} />;
     //...
  }
}
```

And the Layout component provides the context to the Tile like so:

```
const LayoutContext = createContext<{ 
  elements: ElementsType[]; 
  setElements: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ElementsType[]>>; 
} | undefined>(undefined);

export function Layout({ rootElement }: {rootElement?: ElementsType}) {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<ElementsType[]>([]);

  return (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={{ elements, setElements }}>
      {rootElement ? <Tile defaultElement={rootElement}/> : ''}
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

When the button is pressed some elements inside of a layout context changes, but the useEffect does not trigger, even though it has a layout inside of its dependency array.

Comment: What is the value of `layout` in this component?

Answer (score 0):

`layout` is not changing because you are updating your `element` state locally in `Tile` component, and nothing changing in the `LayoutContext`. Use the setter `setElements` (that you are already exposing) from the context and it should work

```
export function Tile({ defaultElement }: {defaultElement?: ElementsType}) {
  const layout = useContext(LayoutContext);
  const [element, setElement] = useState(defaultElement);

  useEffect(() => {
      // layout.setElements(some element)
  }, [layout])

   //...
  }
}
```